# VBA Countifs based one cells.interior.colorindex

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted to Count with `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` with second condition based on `Interior.ColorIndex`.

It is possible? What is wrong with this?

```
Check= WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range(Cells(FirstRow + 1, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp)), "Checking", Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 56)
```

Comment: Not possible with COUNTIFS.  You will need to use a loop.